# How can I force go mod to accept a module that declares its path being different from its go.mod?

Tags: go, go-modules

When I run `go mod tidy`, it breaks because a package imported by my project imports another package using path `github.com/coreos/bbolt`, but when it fetches the package from this path its `go.mod` says its path is `go.etcd.io/bbolt`.

The problem is that both the importing package and the imported package are 3rd party packages. I know I could edit the go module cache to fix it, but it would be a real hell fixing it when new versions of these packages become available.

Partial echoed messages are shown below:

```
    github.com/coreos/etcd/client tested by
    github.com/coreos/etcd/client.test imports
    github.com/coreos/etcd/integration imports
    github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdserver imports
    github.com/coreos/etcd/mvcc/backend imports
    github.com/coreos/bbolt: github.com/coreos/bbolt@v1.3.5: parsing go.mod:
    module declares its path as: go.etcd.io/bbolt
            but was required as: github.com/coreos/bbolt
```

So, how can I fix or work around this situation?

Answer (score 7):

You can fix this solution by using the [replace directive](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace)

Simply add:

```
replace github.com/coreos/bbolt v1.3.5 => go.etcd.io/bbolt v1.3.5
```

at the end of your `go.mod` file

Comment: If that works, it's arguably a bug in the `go` command — and one that I'm likely to fix as part of https://golang.org/issue/26904, which will address this sort of “renamed module” use-case more directly. 

Comment: a) You're right. The problem was that I was suspicious whether this was a temporary change of `bbolt` or not, and didn't want to change the codebase for that.   For a solid fix, changing the import paths is a better solution b) I too am a long time follower of #26904, since you are the maintainer: good luck and thanks

Answer (score 3):

The mismatched path implies that your dependency (`github.com/coreos/etcd/mvcc/backend`) is written against an old version of the `bbolt` repository — one that predates [commit e65d4d](https://github.com/etcd-io/bbolt/commit/e65d4d5d27e82efe8e16175a11ec2f6e8067c990).

---

I notice that the [current `go.mod` file](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/2a0f8f073892ea5ea9a4a467dbbc16d1576fd084/go.mod#L1) in the `github.com/etcd-io/etcd` repo specifies its module path as `go.etcd.io/etcd/v3`.

So the most robust fix for you is probably to update to that path, which you can do by changing your `import` statements to refer to the new canonical import path and running `go mod tidy` to update your dependencies accordingly:

```
sed -i s,github.com/coreos/etcd,go.etcd.io/etcd/v3,g $(find . -name '*.go')
go mod tidy
```

---

Barring that, you could explicitly choose a version of `github.com/coreos/bbolt` that matches the older import path. I notice that the highest version for that module listed at https://beta.pkg.go.dev/github.com/etcd-io/bbolt?tab=versions is `v1.3.3`, and `v1.3.4` does seem to add [a `go.mod` file with the updated path](https://github.com/etcd-io/bbolt/blob/68cc10a767ea1c6b9e8dcb9847317ff192d6d974/go.mod#L1). So as a fallback, you could try:

```
go get -d github.com/coreos/bbolt@v1.3.3
```

The downside to that approach is that `v1.3.3` is the end of the line: you wouldn't be able to pull in bug-fixes after that point, because those fixes are all at the `go.etcd.io` path.

Comment: An aside: `bbolt` adding a `go.mod` file in a patch release is not a great choice as far as [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) goes — adding a `go.mod` file is arguably “add[ing] functionality”, not a “backwards compatible bug [fix]”. But that's not a problem you or they can feasibly address at this point. 

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the replace directive with the command line, as example:

```
go mod edit -replace github.com/pselle/bar=/Users/pselle/Projects/bar
```

[More info in this article](https://thewebivore.com/using-replace-in-go-mod-to-point-to-your-local-module/)